# Hexadecimal floating-point constants in C

Tags: c, floating-point, hex

I've got a hexadecimal floating-point constant which I'd like to declare directly in my C program, and avoid conversion.  I believe it must be normalized first, right?  How do I normalize it and declare it?

```
// hex constant 0xDE.488631  
double val = 0xDE.488631; // Error must have exponent.
double val = 0x0.DE488631p-2;  // Pretty sure this is wrong.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use an exponent of `0`:

```
float val = 0xDE.488641p0;
```

Which in more normal looking notation means DE.488641×2<sup>0</sup> (in base 16, of course).  Your guess was close - the exponent is a *binary* exponent, not a hex exponent, though.  You're also using a negative exponent when you want to have a positive exponent.  Correcting your second example, you can use:

```
float val = 0x0.DE488631p8;
```

Which in regular mathematical notation means 0.DE488631×2<sup>8</sup>, or equivalently with a  hexadecimal base for the exponent, 0.DE488631×16<sup>2</sup>.

I think using an exponent of `0` is a lot easier to understand unless you have some reason to use the form from your second example.

Comment: Exactly.  Normalization is not necessary; exponents are.

Answer (score 1):

The C99 Standard specifies that a hexadecimal floating point constant must have an exponent:

> #### §6.4.4.2 Floating constants
>
> ```
>     hexadecimal-floating-constant:  
>         hexadecimal-prefix hexadecimal-fractional-constant  
>             binary-exponent-part floating-suffix[opt]  
>         hexadecimal-prefix hexadecimal-digit-sequence  
>             binary-exponent-part floating-suffix[opt]
> ```

From this definition, you can see that only the floating-suffix is optional (i.e. the `f` or `l` that can be appended to a floating constant to force a particular floating type). As Carl Norum has already suggested, use an exponent of 0 as a “no-op”.